# Spring cloud: Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I have an application in which I would like to add Spring Cloud Netlix Eureka.

I've added this service discovery to 2 other services without issues. In the third service, which is the more complex one, after adding:

Spring cloud dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

bootstrap.properties, with application name

```
spring.application.name=my-app
```

Eureka related configuration in application.properties

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${random.int}
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
```

Enabling the Eureka client with annothing on the Application class

```
@EnableEurekaClient
```

After this with launching the app I'm getting the following error:

```
2018-06-25 18:22:31.229 ERROR 7862 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f4aa1064]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

I'm not sure why somehow there's an issue creating a data source.
The only difference with the other services is that this one connects to a postgres database.

I've pinpointed the issue here, in the "DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration" class:

[image]

However, I'm still not sure why only with spring cloud on the classpath.

Also, I doubt it's related since removing this doesn't remove the issue but I also added a new Bean:

```
@LoadBalanced
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
  return builder.build();
}
```

And used like so in a class:

```
private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Autowired
public AudienceConsoleAudienceFetcher(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
  this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}
```

This replaces what I had before in that same class:

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
```

Edit:

Here is the pom.xml and Application class: https://gist.github.com/nWidart/1f3a635d6d392afe68d09603c260ed04

Thanks!

Comment: can you please post your stacktrace? The exception you put here isn't quite helpful.

Comment: Hello, I don't have one, this is the only thing I have in output besides the usual INFO logs.

Comment: Can you add your `pom.xml` and Application.java class? Also, are your using spring boot actuator by any chance?

Comment: I've added the gist to the post with the pom.xml and application class. I am indeed using actuator. The (long) error comes from there, HealthEndpointConfiguration > HealthEndpoint >DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.

Comment: I have commented out the actuator dependency, but same error. Not sure how but it's still saying something about the 'healthEndpoint',

Comment: For those interested, seems to be a known (unresolved) bug...  https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/355#issuecomment-385169003